# Dropdown menu not appearing in the form rendered by django in a template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to show a drop-down menu in a Django Template but it does not appear. Here is my code:

**Post Model:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    category_choices = (
        ('technology', 'Technology'),
        ('personal', 'Personal'),
        ('poetry', 'Poetry'),
        ('rants', 'Rants'),
        ('random', 'Random'),
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    body = models.TextField()
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=category_choices, default='technology')
```

**Form:**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'category', 'body')
```

**Template:**

```
<h1>New post</h1>
<div class="row">
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'post_new' %}" class="col s12 m12 l12"> {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**And this is how it looks in a browser:**
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMXMb.png]

Comment: Well the label is rendered. If you inspect the html there's some markup maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `{{ form.category }}` in form tag? Just to test.